# SQL integer query, find integer within +/- 1

Tags: mysql, sql

If I want to run an SQL statement like

```
"SELECT integername from tblintegerlist where integerlist ..."
```

I have a list of numbers like

```
integername
1
2
3
4
5
```

so I want results for +/- 1 of the search, so for '4' I would get rows 3,4,5 as the results.

Comment: You don't define what "integerlist" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT integername 
FROM tblintegerlist 
WHERE (integername-<variable>) BETWEEN -1 AND 1
```

Comment: This solution does seem nicer because it avoids repeating the variable name, but applying the calculation to `integername` will most probably prevent the server from using the index on that column, if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your correctly

```
where integername >= n-1 AND integername <= n+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to write a SQL with a > and a < clause.

```
SELECT integername FROM tbintegerlist 
WHERE integername >= @val - 1 AND integername <= @val + 1
```

You may also prefer this:

```
SELECT integername FROM tbintegerlist 
WHERE integername BETWEEN @val - 1 AND @val + 1
```

But, you should remember to check your database to see whether "between" clauses are inclusive or exclusive.  For some databases, "between" means "greater than or equal to the lesser value, and less than the greater value."

Comment: `Between` in MySQL is inclusive.

Comment: Oracle's BETWEEN is inclusive too.

Comment: PostgreSQL's BETWEEN is inclusive: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparison.html